# Rails Engine + omniauth-google-oauth2 + Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

Am writing a rails app and a engine. Engine contains Authentication and Authorization process (Here am using GMail login- google_oauth2 gem). After Successful login i have to start session using Devise gem then i have to redirect to sample app.
Problems:

- How can i start session after Success message from google? because
  here i have to use Devise for session.
- What are all the parameters i have to send to devise then how to call
  devise's session controller from my engine?
- Is there any tutorial to add devise with engine(google-oauth2
  gem) please provide links.

  If question not clear please tell me i will provide some more details

Comment: Your question is very broad. Consider trying stuff yourself first and from what you learn, create more specific questions on areas where you are stuck.

Comment: actually i completed authentication process using google-auth now its redirect to some url in myengine, here i have to start session. 1st how can i add devise with engine

Comment: I think it's more usual to use devise and add in external auth via omniauth (Facebook/twitter/google/...).  See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos#omniauth

Comment: Also, for using devise in an engine: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

Comment: Thanks for your help - I got some idea from above mentioned link